# Changing the number of columns for the New Products grid widget in Magento

Tags: xml, layout, magento, widget

How do I change the number of columns for the New Products grid widget in Magento?

I know I have to update the `layout.xml` file somehow but I'm not sure what to insert.Or maybe do I have to do a layout update in the CMS pages that include the widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CMS page content as widget container:

It is pretty simple, just add column_count parameter in `{{widget type="widget_type" parameter1="value" column_count="your_value"}}` directive.

By the way widget it is a standard Magento block with some pre-configurations, so you can easily specify any block parameter within `{{widget}}` directive.

If you want to use Widget functionality, you can create `etc/widget.xml` in your custom module with this XML:

```
<widgets>
   <new_products>
       <parameters>
           <column_count translate="label">
               <required>1</required>
               <visible>1</visible>
               <value>5</value> <!-- default parameter value -->
               <label>The number of Products in a row</label>
               <type>text</type>
           </column_count>
       </parameters>
   </new_products>
</widgets>
```

It will add a new field to widget form, where an admin user will be able to enter the number of products in a single products row

Have fun with Magento =)

Comment: That's amazing, I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Thank you so much. I've spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to do that, searching all over and to no avail. Going into file after file and reading forum after forum. And it was all so simple. Thank you for posting this info.